# LLN and Consistency are equivalent expressions?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, econometrics

Is it true to claim that LLN produces the property of Consistency? How do we intuitively differentiate between the terms as they seem equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LLNs are theorems about convergence in probability (*weak* consistency) or almost sure convergence (*strong* consistency) for the special case where the sequence of random variables $\{b_N \}$ is made up of sample averages. You could have sequences of random numbers that are not means.